# Keep infomed for Device location will Application in Backgroud

Tags: iphone, background, cllocationmanager

I'am developing an application that keep a WebService informed for device location each 5minute (for exemple) :

So when the application leave the foreground execution and enter background I have to lunch a timer who
1 - Update the device location
2 - Send the location to a web service

How can I perform this action ? Or do you know any code exemple that I can follow to achieve this design ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like anyone gave you a solid answer, so allow me.

There is no iOS approved way of running a 5 minute (or any minute) timer in the background (unless your app is VOIP or music). What you CAN do is register your app as requiring location services in the background (edit the info.plist and add a key Required Background Modes and then add a value App registers for location updates. What this means is your locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation: method and corresponding region monitoring/SLC methods will fire on location change, but Timers will not work at all.

The reason why is that timers require a run loop (a thread executing code) to be running and must piggy-back on that thread, but when the app is in the background even when executing code from the LocationManager, the run loop that executes the code almost always finishes before your timer would go off.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. My App is designed to tracks continuously a driver ! so a frequente update is important because of the speed and it have to be precise and not to update on significant change ! this why I am searching for Time based update.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do this (on iOS).

(unless your app requests permissions that are meant for Navigation apps)

Comment: Yes my app is designed to be Navigation Related!

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10 This has all that you want (location events in the background)

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Aladdin Gallas,

I have developed a simple application that supports background location updates for iOS and Android in Xamarin.

The app pushes a new location every 2 seconds (you can change it to 5 minutes if you want to).

There is a feature I haven't been able to add; it is to keep the service up when the user closes the app (for iPhone). Other than that, as long as the app is open, even if the phone is locked, the service keeps running.

You can take a look at the application as a reference if it helps.

[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/shernandezp/XamarinForms.LocationService)